# TravaOpenJDK new JVM option -XX:HotswapAgent, difference between fatjar and core modes?

Tags: java, java-11, hotswapagent

TravaOpenJDK [introduced a new JVM option -XX:HotswapAgent in version 11.0.9](https://github.com/TravaOpenJDK/trava-jdk-11-dcevm/releases).

There are three modes to enable HotswapAgent, `fatjar`, `core` and `external`.

What is the difference between `fatjar` and `core`?

Comment: I betlieve there is closed issue asking the same thing. https://github.com/TravaOpenJDK/trava-jdk-11-dcevm/issues/31

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because this [answer is hidden in a closed issue](https://github.com/TravaOpenJDK/trava-jdk-11-dcevm/issues/31) as @papaya said, i leave it here as reference

> HotswapAgent **core** has no plugin except core JVM plugins. Then it is
> faster since less scanning tasks are necessary to be done, less class
> copying to target classloaders, there is no need to disable plugins.
> You choose only what you want.

Loaded plugins are visible in the log, "HOTSWAP AGENT: 15:43:42.059 INFO (org.hotswap.agent.config.PluginRegistry) - Discovered plugins:"

For `core`: Hotswapper, WatchResources, AnonymousClassPatch, ClassInitPlugin, JdkPlugin

For `fatjar`: dkPlugin, Hotswapper, WatchResources, ClassInitPlugin, AnonymousClassPatch, Hibernate, Hibernate3JPA, Hibernate3, Spring, Jersey1, Jersey2, Jetty, Tomcat, ZK, Logback, Log4j2, MyFaces, Mojarra, Omnifaces, ELResolver, WildFlyELResolver, OsgiEquinox, Owb, Proxy, WebObjects, Weld, JBossModules, ResteasyRegistry, Deltaspike, GlassFish, Vaadin, Wicket, CxfJAXRS, FreeMarker, Undertow, MyBatis

Comment: And which of these are needed for simple hot code replacement from an IDE?